# Create an histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a banal question. I have a dataset that contains the variable AgeXX, with the ages of 2000 people observed (from 21 to 65)

Now I want to plot an histogram representing the distribution of AgeXX, with a binwidth=4.

I tried something like that:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=AgeXX)+ geom_histogram(binwidth = 4)
```

but it does not work since AgeXX is discrete, not continuous

Comment: Does `AgeXX` is a factor ? or a character vector ? Try: `aes(x= as.numeric(as.character(AgeXX)))`

Comment: You should check this https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/blob/master/data-visualization-2.1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult without a minimal, but as long as your variable `AgeXX` is either an `integer` or a `numeric` you shouldn't have any issue. In case the variable is either a `factor` or a `character`, you have to recast it as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat$AgeXX = as.integer( AgeXX )
ggplot(dat, aes( x = AgeXX ) ) +
    geom_histogram( binwidth = 4 )
```